# Spring Data MongoDB array match

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We are storing objectIds in array in a document.

```
{
 "members": [  ObjectId("a"), ObjectId("b"), ObjectId("c") ]
}
```

(storing members' ID here)

Now we get list of members in argument to check 'OR'ed condition to validate membership

```
memArray={"b","c","d"}
```

We want to build query which will return true if any one member of memArray is present in "members".  In this case, memArray is having "b" which is present in "members", so it should be positive match and return true.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$elemMatch` with `$in` operator. Try this:

```
Query query = new Query();   
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("members").elemMatch(Criteria.in(memArray));
```

Make sure that the datatypes of the elements in the `members` array and in the `memArray` are the same, either `ObjectId` or `String`.

Comment: Why this is working I don't know Criteria.in(memArray). Criteria.in not working :(

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?